# Doesn't print a killed node process with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, process, kill

I want to simulate a crash with Node.js by using `process.kill`. I did a basic app with express.js in terminal #1

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hi!');
});

const server = app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server ready'));

console.log(process.pid);

process.on('SIGINT', function () {
  console.log('Simulate crash');
});
```

Then, I'm running in another terminal (terminal #2) a node file that kill the process of terminal #1

**kill.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const args = process.argv.slice(2)[0];

process.kill(args, 'SIGINT');
```

So when I run kill.js with the following command `$ node kill.js YOURPROCESSPID` in the terminal #2, it didn't print the "simulate crash" in the terminal #1. I'd like to know how to make this happen. Thank you.

I also added the console down here.

[image: console]

Comment: Works for me. I can't reproduce it on Linux.

Comment: Are you on windows?  `Windows does not support signals so has no equivalent to termination by signal,`

Comment: Yes I am on windows 10